# React 16 upgrade results in eslint error explosion

Tags: reactjs, eslint

has anyone seen upgrade to react 16 break all eslint rules?

i've encountered this twice. once when I performed a broad swath of updates to npm packages. Then again when I took a very granular approach*.

here is the upgrade that resulted in copious eslint messages:

```
-"react": "15.6.2",
+"react": "16.0.0",
-"react-dom": "15.6.2",
+"react-dom": "16.0.0",
"react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
-"react-router": "3.2.0",
+"react-router": "4.2.0",
```

lint messages occur when running webpack-dev-server, and include these examples.

```
Use object destructuring  prefer-destructuring
Closing tag of a multiline JSX expression must be on its own line
Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 27
defaultProp "currentInput" defined for isRequired propType
Block must not be padded by blank lines
```

*performed jest testing, lint, and integration testing and checked in one family of upgrades at a time.

when this happened before, I went and attempted to fix the reported eslint issues, but did not get React 16 to run.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't update eslint ?

Comment: Another thing I see is the upgrade of react-router which is not related, in itself, to react 16 update.
(I know that to keep on using react-router you need to update it to be compatible with react 16.)

Do you use npm or yarn? Can you do a npm/yarn list eslint?

Comment: @GabrielBleu i upgraded eslint to the very latest *several steps before*, with testing and linting at each step.

Comment: @ChrisR using npm. here is listing output.
    npm ls eslint
    mms-ui@0.1.7 /path/to/project
    ├── eslint@4.10.0
    ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY expect@21.2.1
    └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0
    
    npm ERR! peer dep missing: expect@^1.0.0, required by expect-    jsx@4.0.0
    npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0, required by redux-devtools@3.4.0

Comment: @ChrisR i rolled back react-router and did a clean install. same eslint errors.

Comment: I am sorry, I must admit I have no idea to solve this issue.